# How to change a word in theme?

Tags: translation

I am new in wordpress, and I want to change a word in theme,for example in one of pages I have "view all" word, I want to change it to "see all"
How can i do this?

Comment: whaT is your theme name?

Comment: How about searching for `view all` in your theme project and replacing that to `see all`. Do you have that skill.?

Comment: yes i have, i searched, but there are many pages founded, like this code "<?php _e( 'View All' ); ?>"

Comment: There are solutions, let me check...

Comment: i exactly dont know which file i should change and also which code......!!!!

Comment: What is your page URL where you like to update the text?

Comment: http://bi.artarad.ir/blog/

Comment: This looks to me more like the menu item @mahsash5.

Comment: no in menu i cant see it :( :( :(

Comment: in my list there is all of them except these one :( :(

Comment: OK, no worries, I will prepare the answer for you.

Comment: I tried to reply in very general way. Please consider my effort by accepting my answer @mahsash5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some would say it is hard to answer based on the few information you provided.

However, the answer may be general enough to cover many more problems similar to your case.

First I would install this [plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/show-current-template/).

Check the screenshots section for more info:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/show-current-template/screenshots/

It will provide you the list of files in use. This may be handy when you search where to edit your theme.

Editing themes directly is not recommended, but if you don't care and just need to make it work than it is OK.

Normally you would create the child theme, or work on your translation for the theme.

You can use this kind of hooking to replace some string with another string for the whole theme if you add this to the `functions.php` file

```
function _20170116_replace_text ( $text ) {
    // possible add the condition when ...
    if ($text == 'View All'){$text = 'See All';}
    return $text;

}
add_filter( 'gettext', '_20170116_replace_text' );
```

Check this and let me know if this works. With the `show-current-template` you can thinker the condition when to replace this text.

The condition you need to add to `20170116_replace_text` may look like this:

```
if (in_array( $GLOBALS['pagenow'], array( 'your-page.php' ) )) {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your theme is using something like `<?php _e( 'View All' ); ?>` to render the texts, then it is probably using a language file that contains every string on the template.

1. Download [this](https://poedit.net/) application. It can be used to translate the wordpress language files.
2. Verify that there is a folder named `langauge` in your theme's folder. Browse inside the folder, and you will find some files in `.po` and `.mo` extension.
3. Use Poedit to translate the proper file based on your need. It will be `en_US.po` in case you are using english as your main language.
4. If the file `en_US.po` didn't exist, then you can advance with other solutions.